# Post Gallery list attachments except the one used as post thumbnail

Tags: attachments, images, thumbnails

I'm doing gallery in a single post after the post thumbnail. So I list all the post attachment with the image type (with the following query) but I want to exclude the post thumbnail.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
```

My first idea was to compare the thumbnail full size url with each attachment src.

```
$large_image_url = "";
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
    $large_image_url = parse_url($large_image_url[0], PHP_URL_PATH);
/* 
 *  [...] 
 */
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
foreach($images as $image){
    $big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'full' );
    $img_url = $big_array[0];
    if(!empty($large_image_url) && $large_image_url == $img_url){
    continue;
    }
    array_push($gallery, array(
            'dirname' => dirname($img_url),
            'filepath' => parse_url($img_url, PHP_URL_PATH),
            'ID' => $image->ID
        ));
}
```

But actually it doesn't work yet. Does someone know a simpler or neater way to do so ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. »But actually it doesn't work yet.« isn't quite helpful. Maybe you want to add some more details? Adding some comments to your code would help to see your intentions and seeing your error messages (`WP_DEBUG` to `true` in the wp-config.php) also helps. Btw: Your `if( has_post_thumbnail() ) :` has no `endif;` - where should that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `exclude` parameter.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id